# Effectively using redis and mongo for hierarchical listing api

Tags: mongodb, redis

I am storing files and folder hierarchy in a mongo database, something similar to.

```
{id: 1, is_root: true, name: "root", type: "folder"}
{id: 2, name: "folder1", type: "folder", parent_id: 1}
{id: 3, name: "f1.txt", type: "file", parent_id: 2}
{id: 4, name: "f2.txt", type: "file", parent_id: 2}
{id: 5, name: "f3.txt", type: "file", parent_id: 2}
{id: 6, name: "f4.txt", type: "file", parent_id: 2}
```

Now when retrieving all the child of folder1, we need to query mongo for all the nodes having parent_id=2, it works fine.

Recently to improve the performance I started exploring redis, I just wanted to explore and understand how to leverage redis cache when retrieving data from mongo.

Scenario 1:
It might happen that none of the child exists on the cache.

Scenario 2:
It might happen that all of the child exists on the cache.

Scenario 3:
It might happen one or more of the child exists on the cache.

What is the best way of retrieving listing data in such scenarios leveraging the data stored in the redis cache?

Comment: what backend language are you using

Comment: I am using java (spring boot)